# what's the slide's right box used for?

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

This is a Microsoft Build 2015 conference's power point. I found every slide's right side has a list of color boxes, but none of them can be selecting.

What's these boxes used for and how can I create them?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This kind of thing is quite commonly done by template builders when they want presentations to follow approved "branding".  The color patches make it easier for users to use colors that fit the branding standards.  I'm guessing that the patches include the RGB values for each color ... too small to see here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just not a programming question.

Comment: how to close questions?

Comment: @sendreams; see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information

Comment: why can not ask a question? there has been several days, but all my question have at least one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "boxes" are only a template that you can use for every powerpoint you'll make. So can you create an own style.

Go to your slide and right click. choose the option storyboarding > edit layout. 
From now on can you edit your "boxes".

[image]

[image]

If you save that you that as a `.thmx` file, you can use that again for other powerpoints.

Comment: i cannot ask question anymore, and i can't delete this question, how can i do?

Comment: @sendreams: You can't delete this question because this question has an answer. By a quick search on the help center I've found this where you can find more information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: How can I get out of a question ban?

The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.

Stack Exchange cannot lift question bans by request.

Comment: The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out". Begin by fixing your existing questions; do not just post the same question again. All questions are expected to be useful to future visitors, too, so put effort into writing with proper grammar and spelling, formatting your post so it can be read easily, and providing as much detail as possible about your problem and what you have already tried.

Comment: i can not find any useful information from these message.

Comment: @sendreams: question bans are not funny, I think it's beter (maby I go say anything offensive to SO) to create a new account and start over again. PS your question ban can come because questions about ms office and powerpoint are off topic. I can't see any bad questions on your profile. Maby also by other deleted questions.

Comment: @sendreams: or if you can talk Japanese start here: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Is there a complaint channel?

Comment: @sendreams: maby try on meta but no quarantine that your question get a up vote.

Comment: if i get a up vote, the ban will be disappear?

Comment: @sendreams: i think you must do more than only give a vote to a question. I think it's more for delete or close other persons questions. Only things for high reputation users.

Comment: @sendreams: note also that meta is not a good complaint channel. Meta more like "I've a problem and what can I do"-channel.

Comment: @sendreams: ps can you edit this question, maby I can remove the downvote.

Comment: thank you for your help, but still can't ask question. maybe i should create a new account. thanks a lot.

Comment: @sendreams: I've found a way to get out of your question ban: Answer on a question and get one or more upvotes and must be accepted. I hope you could read this and it will help. Could you say me anything if you're out of the ban?

Comment: you are right, the ban has been get out of, i can ask question again. haha~, thank  you very much.